# Is there a way to pull coordinates that fall in a certain state out of an array of lats and lons in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an array with data for coordinate points that cover the Northeastern section of the US.  Is there any way to pull out only the coordinates that fall in a certain state in this region?  For example, pull out all the coordinates that fall in New York.  Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Care to share some data  or code so we have some idea of what you're working with?

Comment: Not in the standard library, no

Comment: Of course there's a way. What problems are you having with your way?

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1425/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy) could do the trick.

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
g = Nominatim()
location = g.reverse("43.0667, -89.4")  # Reverse lookup of Madison, WI
print(location.raw['address']['state'])
```

You could pass all of your lat/lon pairs to the service, store the location objects returned, and filter however you like.

The raw location data returned looks like:

```
{'address': {'city': 'Madison',
  'clinic': '1 South Park UW Health Clinic',
  'country': 'United States of America',
  'country_code': 'us',
  'county': 'Dane County',
  'neighbourhood': 'Preglers Addition',
  'postcode': '53715',
  'road': 'Braxton Place',
  'state': 'Wisconsin',
  'suburb': 'Monona Bay'},
 'display_name': '1 South Park UW Health Clinic, Braxton Place, Preglers Addition, Monona Bay, Madison, Dane County, Wisconsin, 53715, United States of America',
 'lat': '43.06697945',
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright',
 'lon': '-89.4000472713021',
 'osm_id': '102236889',
 'osm_type': 'way',
 'place_id': '2569590902'}
```